# TypeError: Cannot read property 'TEXT_TYPE' of undefined (BarcodeScanner)

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am using Ionic with BarcodeScanner that can be found [here](https://github.com/wildabeast/BarcodeScanner).
This is my code to encode a piece of text:

```
$scope.GenerateBarcode = function () {
    $cordovaBarcodeScanner.encode($cordovaBarcodeScanner.Encode.TEXT_TYPE, "1", function(result){
        console.log("result:" + result);},
      function(fail){
        console.log("encoding failed: " + fail);}
      )  };
```

However, I am getting the error in the question. This is weird since the plugin code that I use is:

```
function BarcodeScanner() {

/**
 * Encoding constants.
 *
 * @type Object
 */
this.Encode = {
    TEXT_TYPE: "TEXT_TYPE",
    EMAIL_TYPE: "EMAIL_TYPE",
    PHONE_TYPE: "PHONE_TYPE",
    SMS_TYPE: "SMS_TYPE"
  .......
```

I am accessing the object correctly as in the website (example in Cordova). Where is this error comming from?

Comment: Try to write that code in deviceready function

Comment: Did you try using the newer version of the plugin: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner?

Comment: I have used it scan a barcode and it works fine. And yes I have used the newer version

Answer (score 0):

Please note this part of documentation

```
 $cordovaBarcodeScanner
      .encode(BarcodeScanner.Encode.TEXT_TYPE, "http://www.nytimes.com")
      .then(function(success) {
        // Success!
      }, function(error) {
        // An error occurred
      });
```

I assume that you can't access the types with `$cordovaBarcodeScanner`. You need to write `cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.Encode.TEXT_TYPE` or maybe it works if you just write `BarcodeScanner.Encode.TEXT_TYPE`.

Comment: Hello, I tries what you suggested but now I get a "ReferenceError: BarcodeScanner is not defined". And the same with the latter

Answer (score 0):

```
$cordovaBarcodeScanner
                .encode("TEXT_TYPE", "Your text here")
                .then(function (success) {
                    console.log(success);
                    // Success!
                }, function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                    // An error occurred
                });
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation on the code in your answer.